# How to disable multitouch (multiple touches)

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a nice clean way to disable multiple touches on the canvas at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code you've started on? Are you using the touch api for Fabric.js or native javascript touch handlers?

Comment: Im using the touch API for fabricJS. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fabric.js uses Event.js for touch handling. I couldn't figure out which options could be passed into the canvas constructor, but you might try `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {maxFingers:1})`.

Another option might be to use `event.preventDefault()` inside the handlers for pinch and rotate, to cancel 2 finger gestures.  Here are the number of 'pointers' and their actions defined for that library:

> 1  : click, dblclick, dbltap
>     1+ : tap, longpress, drag, swipe
>     2+ : pinch, rotate

If either of those aren't what you need, you will need to set up event listeners for touchstart, touchmove, etc. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Calling_preventDefault()_only_on_a_second_touch) page describes how to listen for all touches, so just call preventDefault for each one after the first.